# How to filter series without filtering calculated series in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a chart in ssrs with a value, a target value and a moverage average.
I only want to show the last 10 weeks, so at chart properties I added a filter which shows only the last 10 weeks. But now my moving average also starts calculating in the last 10 weeks. So every -10th week the moving average has the same value as the real value.

How can I filter the series with value, but not filter the moving average?

Comment: Can you post your SQL statement? I find it's easier to filter the SQL. I can post an example of a CTE that may solve your issue.

Comment: Its not possible to filter in sql, because I use this statement for multiple tables, where I don't need the filter

Comment: Sorry unfortunately I cannot find a workaround for rolling average

Comment: Nevermind, thanks for your time and thoughts!